# Remove the specific digits from numbers and keep in data frame

Tags: r

suppose I have following data frame:

```
df<- data_frame(id= c(001200567, 013009887, 014009344, 015009875,016004556),cost = (10.5:14.5))
```

for column `id` I want just to keep digit `2` and `3`. I have tried  `df <- substr(df$id,2,3)` bu it does not work.
expected output:

```
     id  cost
 
1     1  10.5
2    13  11.5
3    14  12.5
4    15  13.5
5    16  14.5
```

Comment: Is `id` numeric or character? If I use `df<- data_frame(id= c("001200567", "013009887", "014009344", "015009875","016004556"),cost = (10.5:14.5))` then your solution gives the expected outcome.
If it is indeed numeric, the trailing 0s are directly removed and not present in `df`.

Comment: id is character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `id` is a character, we have

```
df<- data_frame(id= c("001200567", "013009887", "014009344", "015009875","016004556"),cost = (10.5:14.5))
```

Using `substr(df$id,2,3)` we would get `01` instead of `1` for the first entry, however we can remove the trailing 0 by making it numeric and then a character again:

```
df$id <- as.character(as.numeric(substr(df$id,2,3)))
```

This gives:

```
> df
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  id     cost
  <chr> <dbl>
1 1      10.5
2 13     11.5
3 14     12.5
4 15     13.5
5 16     14.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, based on `tidyverse` (`stringr::str_sub` allows to extract sub-strings, given their start and end positions):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(id= c("001200567", "013009887", "014009344", "015009875","016004556"),cost = (10.5:14.5))

df %>% 
  mutate(id = str_sub(id, 2, 3)) %>% 
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)

#>   id cost
#> 1  1 10.5
#> 2 13 11.5
#> 3 14 12.5
#> 4 15 13.5
#> 5 16 14.5
```